# Does 64 Bit AMD Works on intell core 2 duo?

Tags: 64-bit, intel, iso, amd-processor

Does 64 Bit AMD Works on intell core 2 duo?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The AMD64 architecture was developed by AMD as an extension to the Intel x86 architecture. It is implemented by AMD and Intel in consumer-grade 64-bit CPUs. AMD64 is alternately called x86-64 (which makes its Intel heritage more apparent).